# How to get the number of entries to an array to compare with an int?

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I had a quick question on comparing the amount of entries in an array to a int.  For example,
TO CLEAR UP ANY CONFUSION I WANT TO KNOW HOW MANY WORDS THERE ARE IN THE ARRAY NOT CHARACTERS
    int i = 0;

```
string[] array = {"bob", "john"};

if(i == int.Parse(array))
{
    //int i should equal 2 for this if statement to be true
}
```

SO that was just an example so you get the idea here's the real code.

```
          if(i == int.Parse(split))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Teams are successfully made");
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Length propery of the array as:

```
if(i == array.Length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
if (i == array.Length)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Teams are successfully made");
    break;
}
```

The [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is a `1` based number. That means if your array has `3` items in it, `Length` will be `3`, however if you want to reference the third item in the array, you will have to use an index of `2` because the reference is `0` based. See the following example:

```
string[] someArray = { "arrays", "are", "amazing" };

Console.WriteLine(someArray.Length); // Prints 3
Console.WriteLine(someArray[2]); // Prints "amazing"
Console.WriteLine(someArray[someArray.Length]); // Blows up because there is no
                                                // element of the array with
                                                // index of 3.
Console.WriteLine(someArray[someArray.Length - 1]); // Prints "amazing"
```